# Create IPA with symbols using xcrun

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, xcrun

I noticed a different when creating an .ipa file manually using `xcrun` than exporting it from xcode. The `xcrun` version doesn't have any symbols included with the .ipa.

I was wondering what's the best way to create an .ipa with symbols (no reason not to send them) manually from the command line, I'm using TeamCity CI to generate our production .ipa files.

I use the following command line to generate the IPA -

```
/usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app" -o "~/MyApp.ipa" --sign "<HIDDEN>" --embed "<HIDDEN>"
```

I run it after invoking `xcodebuild` so the `Release-iphoneos` folder got the latest release version of my app.

Comment: You can check  http://girijeshkumar2007.blogspot.in/2014/10/create-ipa-from-terminal-for-xcode-6.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer myself -

In Xcode 7 Apple added the ability to specify export options plist file to better control the .ipa file creation.
One of the options there is `<key>uploadSymbols</key>` that does exactly what I need.

http://www.matrixprojects.net/p/xcodebuild-export-options-plist